# Android paging and grouping models

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging, android-paging-library

I have MVVM-like architecture, data flow is the following:

- I have data (image src url + linked data) in SQLite
- I have Repository layer and method like this:

  `fun <T> getPhotos(): LiveData<PagedList<PhotoInfo>>`
- I'm using `androidx.paging` library v.2 and it's `PagedListAdapter` as adapter for my `RecyclerView`

Now I want to group data by some field, f.e. by date and have ability to have groups to be either horizontal (with horizontal scrolling) or vertical.

I went through existing answers & solutions for similar issue and here're options I found:

**Option 1**

I can update query to group data and insert 'special' rows as separators.
Then in Adapter I can have some branching logic to handle 'regular' rows and 'separators'.

I don't like this option because it involves this undesirable change of SQL query. Also I can't imagine how to implement 'horizontal' group scrolling in this case.

**Option 2**

I can have nested recycler views, but in this case I don't know how to update my code so that I could have `PagedList<PhotoGroup>` from 'linear' `PagedList<PhotoInfo>`.

The only thing I can think:

- have two methods in repository, which return 'paged' data, for groups and item in a particular group, like:

  - `fun <T> getPhotoGroups(): LiveData<PagedList<PhotoGroup>>`
  - `fun <T> getPhotosForGroup(groupId: Long): LiveData<PagedList<PhotoInfo>>`
- every group has it's own PagedList and RecyclerView.

But I'm afraid it can be over-complicated and might have overhead. Also not sure it will work fine if I have parent RecyclerView and child RecyclerView in the same direction (vertical)

I have a strong feeling I'm missing something and over-complicating things.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve visually?

Comment: If you are using Paging 3 library have you checked https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform#separators ?